# Knock someone down to; Talk someone down to

Tags: word-usage, usage

> I talked the shopkeeper down to X. (price)
>
> I knocked the shopkeeper down to X. (price)

What sounds better "talk down" or "knock down"?

> Can't you knock the price down to X?
>
> Can't you drop the price to X?

Comment: If you knock down the shopkeeper, I doubt he'll be open to price negotiation...

Comment: ***Knock / talked / negotiated / bargained / haggled / etc.*** are all effectively synonyms for the cited context (some more formal, other more informal). But if we switch the subject from "buyer" to "seller" most of them no longer work, so *The shopkeeper talked the price down to £100* just sounds bizarre (but *The shopkeeper **knocked** the price down to £100* is fine).

Answer (score 2):

"Knock down" usually only refers to monetary transactions, for example:

> I knocked him down on price.

"Talk down" has a much wider usage and could refer to persuading anyone to "come down" from a physical place, a mental position or standpoint. So you *could* use it for knocking down a price, but for other things too.

> - I talked him down on price
> - He was angry about it, but I managed to talk him down.
> - The policeman talked him down from the ledge.

Comment: So what's more common in my context?